# linear operators diagonalisation

Tags: linear-algebra

Give an example of two diagonizable linear operators $f$ and $g \in \mathbb{R}^2$, for which $5f - 2g$ is not diagonizable.

Comment: What did you try? We are not here to do your homework but to help you. Not diagonal or not diagonizable?

Comment: It’s not a homework, but a question. Diagonizable. I can do this for one linear operator, but don’t know how to do it for two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** Note that
$$\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}-2&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
is a decomposition of a nondiagonizable matrix into two diagonizable ones.

Comment: No, it isn't. Make it $$\pmatrix{2&1\\0&1}+\pmatrix{-2&0\\0&-1}=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}.$$

Comment: Oh right. Thanks!